# Recursion (done)

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, recursion

I wrote this path finding algorithm that should be working, but I'm getting tons of java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. The goal of the program is to find the shortest path from one point to another that costs the least.  Here's my code:

```
public boolean travel(int[][] path, int cX, int cY, int eX, int eY)
{
    boolean returned = false;
    System.out.println("the current X position on the GRID is: "+cX+"the current y position on the GRID is: "+cY);
    path[cX][cY]=1;
    if(cost>lowestCost - grid[cX][cY]){ 
        return false;
    }
    cost += grid[cX][cY];
    if(cX>=eX && cY>=eY){
        return true;
    }
    if(cX+1>=eX && cY+1<eY){
        return false;
    }
    if(cY+1>=eY && cX+1<eX){
        return false;
    }
    if(travel(path,cX+1,cY+1,eX,eY)==true){
        returned=true;
        replace(newBest, path);
    }
    if(travel(path,cX,cY+1,eX,eY)==true){
        returned=true;
        replace(newBest, path);
    }
    if(travel(path,cX+1,cY,eX,eY)==true){
        returned=true;
        replace(newBest, path);
    }


    return(returned);

}
```

cX is the current X position in the array, cY is the current Y position in the array, eX and eY are the destination coordinates. path[][] is the array used to store the path. If you have any answers please tell me! also don't suggest any other algorithms, just some edits to the actual code. grid[][] is the array that stores the cost to go from one to another. Thanks very much

```
 if(travel(newBest,0,0,rows,columns)==true)
                {
                    lowestCost=cost;
                }
```

This is how I call the method to find the shortest path.

This is the entire applet:

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
public class GridWorld extends Applet implements Runnable, MouseListener, KeyListener,     MouseMotionListener
{
public int worldx;
public int worldy;
public int columns;
public int rows;
public int destX, destY;
public int cost, lowestCost;
public boolean sizeD;
public int[][] grid;

public int[][] prevBest;

public int[][] newBest;


Graphics bufferGraphics; //Set up double buffer
Image offscreen;
Thread thread;//Sets up a Thread called thread

public void init()
{
    worldx=1000;
    worldy=1000;
    cost=0;
    lowestCost=5000;
    sizeD=false;
    columns=5;
    rows=5;
    destX=0;
    destY=0;
    grid= new int[rows][columns];
    prevBest= new int[rows][columns];
    newBest = new int[rows][columns];



    offscreen = createImage(worldx,worldy); //create a new image that's the size of the applet DOUBLE BUFFER SET UP
    bufferGraphics = offscreen.getGraphics(); //set bufferGraphics to the graphics of the offscreen image. DOUBLE BUFFER SET UP

    addKeyListener(this);//setup all the listeners
    addMouseListener(this);//setup all the listeners
    addMouseMotionListener(this);//setup all the listeners
    thread = new Thread(this);  //constructs a new thread
    thread.start();             //starts the thread
}//init()
public void fillGrid()
{
    prevBest= new int[rows][columns];
    newBest = new int[rows][columns];
    lowestCost = 0;
    for(int ro = 0;ro<rows;ro++)
    {
        for(int col = 0;col<columns;col++)
        {
                grid[ro][col]=(int)(Math.random()*100);
                newBest[ro][col]=0;
                prevBest[ro][col]=0;
                if(ro==col)
                {
                    prevBest[ro][col]=1;
                    lowestCost+=grid[ro][col];


                }
        }
    }

    destX=(rows-1);
    destY=(columns-1);
}
public boolean baseCase(int ct, int lowct, int destR, int destC, int cX, int cY)
{
    boolean returned=false;
    if(ct>=lowct)
    {
        returned=true;
    }
    if(cX+1==rows)
    {
        returned=true;
    }
    if(cY+1==columns)
    {
        returned=true;
    }
    if(cX==destR && cY==destC)
    {
        returned=true;
    }

    return(returned);
}
public boolean isValid(int x, int y, int[][] path, int eX, int eY) {
    //not valid if: cordinates are into grid dimensions
   if (!((x >= 0 && x < grid.length) && (y >= 0 && y < grid.length)))
       return false;
   //valid if: not visited yet, or is destiny
   if (path[x][y] == 0 || (x == eX && y == eY))
       return true;

   return true;
}
/*public int traverse(int steps, int destR, int destC, int curX, int curY)
{
    int direction = 0;
    if(cost>=lowestCost)
    {
        //System.out.println("Greater cost Base Case");
        direction=4;
    }
    if(curX+1>=destR && curY+1<destC)
    {
        System.out.println("Reached the farthest row Base Case");
        direction=1;
    }
    if(curY+1>=destC && curY+1<destR)
    {
        System.out.println("Reached the farthest columns Base Case");
        direction=2;
    }
    if(curX+1>=destR && curY+1>=destC)
    {
        System.out.println("At destination Base Case");
        direction=4;    
    }
    switch(direction)
    {
        case 0: newBest[curX][curY]=1;
                cost+=grid[curX][curY];
                System.out.println("the current X position on the GRID is: "+curX+"the current y position on the GRID is: "+curY);
                return(traverse(steps+1,destR,destC,curX+1,curY+1)); //diag

        case 1: newBest[curX][curY]=1;
                cost+=grid[curX][curY];
                return(traverse(steps+1,destR,destC,curX,curY+1)); //right

        case 2: newBest[curX][curY]=1;
                cost+=grid[curX][curY];
                return(traverse(steps+1,destR,destC,curX+1,curY));//down

        case 3: 
                return(5000);

        case 4: System.out.println("the Grid's cost is: "+cost);
                return(cost);
        default: return(0);

    }
}*/

 public int[][] replace(int[][] p1, int[][] p2)
 {
    for(int col=0;col<columns;col++)
        {
            for(int ro=0;ro<rows;ro++)
            {
                p1[ro][col]=p2[ro][col];
            }
        }
    return(p1);
 }
public boolean travel(int[][] path, int cX, int cY, int eX, int eY)
{
    boolean returned = false;
    System.out.println("cX: "+ cX+" , cY: "+ cY+", eX: "+eX+", eY: " +eY+" Path 1 length: "+path[0].length+" Path 2 length: "+path[1].length);
    path[cX][cY]=1;
    if(cost>lowestCost - grid[cX][cY]){ 
        System.out.println("1");
        return false;
    }
    cost += grid[cX][cY];

    }
    if(travel(path,cX+1,cY+1,eX,eY)==true && isValid(cX+1,cY+1,newBest,eX,eY)){
        System.out.println("the current X position on the GRID is: "+cX+"the current y position on the GRID is: "+cY);
        returned=true;
        replace(newBest, path);
    }
    if(travel(path,cX,cY+1,eX,eY)==true && isValid(cX,cY+1,newBest,eX,eY)){
        System.out.println("the current X position on the GRID is: "+cX+"the current y position on the GRID is: "+cY);

        returned=true;
        replace(newBest, path);
    }
    if(travel(path,cX+1,cY,eX,eY)==true && isValid(cX+1,cY,newBest,eX,eY)){
        System.out.println("the current X position on the GRID is: "+cX+"the current y position on the GRID is: "+cY);

        returned=true;
        replace(newBest, path);
    }


    return(returned);

}

public void paint(Graphics g) 
{// paint() is used to display things on the screen
    setSize(worldx,worldy);
    //clear the offscreen image
    bufferGraphics.clearRect(0,0,worldx,worldy);
    bufferGraphics.setColor(Color.black);
    //bufferGraphics.fillRect(0,0,worldx,worldy);

    if(sizeD==true)
    {
        if(travel(newBest,0,0,rows,columns)==true)
                {
                    lowestCost=cost;
                }
    }
    for(int ro = 0;ro<rows;ro++)
    {
        for(int col = 0;col<columns;col++)
        {
            if(sizeD==true)
            {

                if(newBest[ro][col]==1)
                {
                    bufferGraphics.setColor(Color.red);
                    bufferGraphics.fillRect((50*col),(50*ro),50,50);
                    bufferGraphics.setColor(Color.black);
                }
                if(prevBest[ro][col]==1)
                {
                    bufferGraphics.setColor(Color.gray);
                    bufferGraphics.fillRect((50*col),(50*ro),50,50);
                    bufferGraphics.setColor(Color.black);
                }

                bufferGraphics.drawLine(0,(50*ro),50*columns,(50*ro));
                bufferGraphics.drawLine((50*col),0,(50*col),50*rows);
                bufferGraphics.drawString(""+grid[ro][col],(50*ro)+25,(50*col)+25);



            }

        }
    }

    if(sizeD==false)
    {
        bufferGraphics.drawRect(200,300,100,100);
        bufferGraphics.drawString("5",250,350);
        bufferGraphics.drawRect(400,300,100,100);
        bufferGraphics.drawString("10",450,350);
        bufferGraphics.drawRect(600,300,100,100);
        bufferGraphics.drawString("20",650,350);
    }


    g.drawImage(offscreen,0,0,worldx,worldy,this);//Draw the screen
}// paint()

public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {

}
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e){

}
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) 
{

}
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) 
{

}
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) 
{
   System.out.println("Mouse entered");
}
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) 
{
   System.out.println("Mouse exited");
}
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) 
{
   System.out.println("Mouse clicked (# of clicks: "+ e.getClickCount() + ")");
   int mX=e.getX();
   int mY=e.getY();
   if(new Rectangle(200,300,100,100).contains(mX,mY) && sizeD==false)
   {
    columns=5;
    rows=5;
    grid= new int[rows][columns];
    fillGrid();
    sizeD=true;
   }
   if(new Rectangle(400,300,100,100).contains(mX,mY) && sizeD==false)
   {
    columns=10;
    rows=10;
    grid= new int[rows][columns];
    fillGrid();
    sizeD=true;

   }
   if(new Rectangle(600,300,100,100).contains(mX,mY) && sizeD==false)
   {
    columns=20;
    rows=20;
    grid= new int[rows][columns];
    fillGrid();
    sizeD=true;
   }

}
public void keyPressed( KeyEvent event ) 
{
    String keyin; // define a non‐public variable to hold the string representing the key input
    keyin = ""+event.getKeyText( event.getKeyCode()); 
    System.out.println("Key pressed "+keyin);
}//keyPressed()
public void keyReleased( KeyEvent event ) 
{
    String keyin;
    keyin = ""+event.getKeyText( event.getKeyCode()); 
    System.out.println ("Key released: "+ keyin);
}//keyReleased()
public void keyTyped( KeyEvent event ) 
{
 char keyin;
keyin = event.getKeyChar(); //getKeyChar() returns the character of the printable key pressed. 
System.out.println ("Key Typed: "+ keyin);
}//keyTyped()
public void update (Graphics g) 
{
    paint(g); 
}//Update the graphics

public void run() 
{
    while(true) // this thread loop forever and runs the paint method and then sleeps.
    {

        repaint();
        try {
        thread.sleep(50);
        }
        catch (Exception e){ }
    }//while
}// run()
```

}//Applet

Comment: What you mean with "grid[][] is the array that stores the cost to go from one to another." ?

Comment: grid [] [] is the multidimensional array that stores the cost for each tile in the grid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a recursive solution with backtraking, code is explained:

```
public class FindShortestPath {

    //the map is represented as a graph, and the graph is represented as an adyacent matrix
    int map[][] = {{-1, 1, 1, 20},    //-1 = there is no edge between two vertexs
                  {-1, -1, 3, 1},
                  {-1, -1, -1, 1},
                  {-1, -1, -1, -1}};
    
    int distSol = Integer.MAX_VALUE;                    //we want to minimize this value
    List<Integer> solution = new ArrayList<Integer>();  //path solution

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new FindShortestPath().start();
    }

    void start() {
        /* In this case we find shortest path from 0 to 3 */
        findShortestPath(new boolean[map.length], 0, 3, 0, new ArrayList<Integer>());
        
        System.out.println("Distance: " + distSol);
        System.out.println(solution.toString());
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param visit   auxiliary array to mark visited
     * @param c       actual vertex
     * @param destiny destiny vertex
     * @param distAct actual distance traveled
     * @param path    actual path traveled
     */
    void findShortestPath(boolean visit[], int c, int destiny, int distAct, List<Integer> path) {
        if (c == destiny) {                             //base case: we reach destiny
            if (distAct <= distSol) {                   //check if actual distance is better than solution                
                distSol = distAct;
                solution = new ArrayList<Integer>(path);   //replace old solution
                solution.add(destiny);
            }
        } else {                                        //recursive case
            path.add(c);                                //add actual vertex as a possible candidate into actual path
            visit[c] = true;

            for (int i = 0; i < map.length; i++) {      //visit every adyacent vertex that was no visited yet
                if (map[c][i] != -1 && !visit[i]) {
                    findShortestPath(visit, i, destiny, distAct + map[c][i], path);
                }
            }

            path.remove(path.size() - 1);               //remove this vertex from the path
            visit[c] = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Output for this example:

> Distance: 2
>
> [0, 2, 3]

**EDIT**

The OP wants the map to be a grid:

```
public class FindShortestPath2 {

    int lowestCost = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    
    int grid[][] = {{0, 9, 0, 0},  
                   { 0, 5, 1, 1},
                   { 0, 0, 2, 0},
                   { 0, 0, 0, 0}};
    
    int sol[][] = new int[4][4];      //this is the path solution
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new FindShortestPath2().start();
    }

    void start() {
        travel(new int[4][4], 0, 0, 2, 2, 0);
        System.out.println("Lowest cost: " + lowestCost);
        printPath(sol);  //print solution
    }

    public void travel(int[][] path, int cX, int cY, int eX, int eY, int cost) {
        if (cX == eX && cY == eY) {    //reach destiny cordinates
            if (cost < lowestCost) {
                lowestCost = cost;
                path[cX][cY] = 1;
                replace(sol, path);             
            }
        } else {
            path[cX][cY] = 1;         //mark path
            
            if (isValid(cX + 1, cY + 1, path, eX, eY)) {    //move in diagonal (rigth-down)       
                travel(path, cX + 1, cY + 1, eX, eY, cost + grid[cX + 1][cY+1]);
            }
            if (isValid(cX, cY + 1, path, eX, eY)) {        //move rigth
                travel(path, cX, cY + 1, eX, eY, cost + grid[cX][cY+1]);
            }
            if (isValid(cX + 1, cY, path, eX, eY)) {        //move down
                travel(path, cX + 1, cY, eX, eY, cost + grid[cX + 1][cY]);
            }

            path[cX][cY] = 0;       //unmark path
        }
    }

    
    boolean isValid(int x, int y, int[][] path, int eX, int eY) {
        //not valid if: cordinates are into grid dimensions
       if (!((x >= 0 && x < grid.length) && (y >= 0 && y < grid.length)))
           return false;
       
       //valid if: not visited yet, or is destiny
       if (path[x][y] == 0 || (x == eX && y == eY))
           return true;
       
       return true;
    }
    
    void replace(int[][] p1, int[][] p2) {
        for (int col = 0; col < p1.length; col++) {
            for (int ro = 0; ro < p1.length; ro++) {
                p1[ro][col] = p2[ro][col];
            }
        }
    }
    
    void printPath(int[][] p) {
        for (int col = 0; col < p.length; col++) {
            for (int ro = 0; ro < p.length; ro++) {
                System.out.print(p[col][ro] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Output for this example:

```
Lowest cost: 2

1 0 0 0 
1 0 0 0 
0 1 1 0 
0 0 0 0
```

Comment: Hey man thanks for the response, but as I mentioned, just some edits to the code, implementing new code is just kinda cheap coding and difficult because a lot of my variables don't fit into that algorithm.

Comment: @JacobAronoff Post your input grid.

Comment: It's a randomly generated grid thats either 5by5, 10by10, or 20by20.

Comment: @JacobAronoff In what corrdinates x, y you start the search?. And what is the initial value of `cost`, and `lowestCost`?

Comment: I start it at 5000 (just a big number), and then reset it in fillGrid() to 0, and then add to it. I start with coords (0,0)

Comment: @JacobAronoff Do you see you move in only three directions?

Comment: Yea, I know my teacher wanted us to only start with diagonal, right, and down

Comment: @JacobAronoff I added another solution without graphs. The map is just a grid, and you move only in diagonal, right or down. Note that you only move to another coordinates if it is valid, so i created another method to check that.

Comment: Oh wow! thanks so much! I believe that solution will work! That code is exactly what I was thinking of when I was writing everything out but I wasn't sure exactly if the recursive should be a void or not, and you sorted it all out! thanks man!

Answer (score 2):

You are getting tons of `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` because you didn't proper manage the flow to enter the last three if-block. The code will enter the last three if-block since you only return the state at `return(returned);` even you have set boundary check (first two if-block). So, `path[cX][cY]` and `grid[cX][cY]` may encounter index out of bound when cX and cY is a large value (depends on the index setup of path and grid).

Also, the checking logic for first four if-block is not in correct order and you should return state when the condition meet.

The first four if-block should rearrange as:

```
if(cost>=lowestCost){ 
    return false;
}
if(cX==eX && cY==eY){
    return true;
}
if(cX+1>=eX && cY+1<eY){
    return false;
}
if(cY+1>=eY && cX+1<eX){
    return false;
}
```

BTW, please ensure your boundary checking (`cX+1>=eX && cY+1<eY` and `cY+1>=eY && cX+1<eX`) is correct. This will makes the code cannot access points in `([eX-1,eX],[0,eY-2])` and `([0,eX-2],[eY-1,eY])`.

One more point, you might get trouble for `cost>=lowestCost` for rare cases like all possible shortest path has cost equal to pre-set value of lowestCost. One way to handle this is remove equal sign.

One more again, you might get trouble for `cost>=lowestCost` for extreme cases like `cost = Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1`. To handle this, you may try

```
if(cost>lowestCost - grid[cX][cY]){ 
    return false;
}
cost += grid[cX][cY];
```

Comment: Thanks hkg279, that solved a lot of it but I'm still getting more issues with the code, its now only one Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 20. Any ideas how to fix? I updated the code in the original post

Answer (score 0):

This may be off topic, but have you tried implementing **Dijkstra's Algorithm** in Java. In the following algorithm, the code u := vertex in Q with min dist[u], searches for the vertex u in the vertex set Q that has the least dist[u] value. length(u, v) returns the length of the edge joining (i.e. the distance between) the two neighbor-nodes u and v. The variable alt on line 17 is the length of the path from the root node to the neighbor node v if it were to go through u. If this path is shorter than the current shortest path recorded for v, that current path is replaced with this alt path. The previous array is populated with a pointer to the "next-hop" node on the source graph to get the shortest route to the source. (taken from Wikipedia's artice on Dijkstra's Algorithm. This work is not my own.

```
function Dijkstra(Graph, source):
  dist[source]  := 0                     // Distance from source to source
  for each vertex v in Graph:            // Initializations
      if v ≠ source
          dist[v]  := infinity           // Unknown distance function from source to v
          previous[v]  := undefined      // Previous node in optimal path from source
      end if 
      add v to Q                         // All nodes initially in Q (unvisited nodes)
  end for

  while Q is not empty:                  // The main loop
      u := vertex in Q with min dist[u]  // Source node in first case
      remove u from Q 

      for each neighbor v of u:           // where v has not yet been removed from Q.
          alt := dist[u] + length(u, v)
          if alt < dist[v]:               // A shorter path to v has been found
              dist[v]  := alt 
              previous[v]  := u 
          end if
      end for
  end while
  return dist[], previous[]
 end function
```